# Sharp Fourth Scale Degree in the Goldberg Variation "Aria"

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, harmony, analysis

My question relates to the C# in the 3rd measure.

I understand that the section eventually modulates to D major which contains that C#, but that does not seem to happen until the 9th measure. What would be the customary harmonic analysis of the 3 measure?

[image: goldberg variations]

Comment: V/V, as bar 4 is V, so bar 3 prepares for it with a dominant of that dominant.

Comment: @Tim there's no A in that measure.  It's vii/V (in first inversion, of course).

Comment: @phoog - doesn't playing the mordent introduce an A into the equation? The feel of bar 3 is A dominant 7.

Comment: @Tim true, I overlooked the ornament.  Still feels like a vii to me.

Comment: Also, even if there were no A in the measure, the chord C#/E/G still functions as a five of five.

Comment: @phoog - so the notes in your vii(o) are C# E G. That's C#o, (the top 3 notes of A7) but as soon as the A appears, it becomes A7, although either will resolve to D.

Comment: @Tim but the A isn't structural, it's ornamental.  I find a synthesized bass line of G-D-A-D to be very awkward and also to change the harmonic character of the piece considerably. This argues in favor of analysing that measure as vii/V.  Furthermore the doubled seventh is very unusual for a V7 chord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are answers in the comments, I thought I'd provide an official one.

You're correct that the music has not yet modulated to D, as evidenced by (among other things) the C♮ that appears in the bass at the end of m. 4.

Measure 4 is clearly a V chord (D), and that C♯ clearly suggests a tonicization of that V chord. When we stack that chord in m. 3 in thirds, we get `C♯–E–G`, which is a vii° triad (the ° means diminished) in the key of D. With the E in the bass it's in first inversion, so this chord is best called a vii°6/V (read "seven-diminished six of five"), which is a very common occurrence in step-descent basses like this one.

And as some of the comments above discuss, if one wishes to include the A in the chord, we're left with `A–C♯–E–G`, which is a V7 chord in D, but now in second inversion. If you include the A, the chord is then best labeled V43/V.

Comment: A 19th century theorist would probably have said that it *does* modulate to the dominant in bars 3 and 4, back to the tonic in bar 5, and to the subdominant (and back to the tonic) in bars 5-6! But the current terminology of "secondary dominants" seems to be an improvement on the old terminology of "passing modulations" for these harmonic progressions.